# Using a php function in javascript

Tags: php, jquery, json

I need to use a php function inside this script which converts the ID into a required format.

```js
function onlineStatus() {  
    $.getJSON('updateusers.php', function(data) {  
        $('#users').html('');
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {  
            $('#users').append('[<span>'+ item.userid +'</span>]');
        });
    });
    setTimeout("onlineStatus()",30000);
}
```

I have tried the following in various ways but I either get nothing or it fails with a missing ) after the argument list.

```
$('#users').append('[<span>'<?php nameFormat('+ item.userid +') ?>'</span>]');
```

I would appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Why don't you just put your nameFormat() function into updateusers.php and return the formatted value in your json ?

Answer (score 4):

PHP functions can only be executed on the server-side. You should probably translate the `nameFormat` function into javascript so you can use it on the client-side.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to run this command on the server side before sending the script to the user, you have forgotten to echo the statement. Either type

```
$('#users').append('[<span>'<?php echo nameFormat('+ item.userid +'); ?>'</span>]');
```

or

```
$('#users').append('[<span>'<?=nameFormat('+ item.userid +')?>'</span>]');
```

... unless ofcourse the function *nameFormat* allready does an echo.

Comment: $('#users').append('[<span>'<a href=viewuser.php?u=><font color= #000000></font></a>'</span>]');

Answer (score 1):

It's one side connection. You can use javascript in php, but you can't use php in javascript.
For example:

You can assign variable in php, and than use it in JS.

```
var a = <?php echo $a ?>;
```

The same thing you can do with functions ;)